# GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Backend Error [500] when streaming to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm streaming data to BigQuery for the past year or so from a service in Azure written in c# and recently started to get increasing amount of the following errors (most of the requests succeed):

> Message: [GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError An
>   internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. [500]
>   Errors [
>       Message[An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.] Location[ - ] Reason[internalError] Domain[global] ] ]

This is the code I'm using in my service:

```
public async Task<TableDataInsertAllResponse> Update(List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> rows, string tableSuffix)
        {
            var request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest {Rows = rows, TemplateSuffix = tableSuffix};
            var insertRequest = mBigqueryService.Tabledata.InsertAll(request, ProjectId, mDatasetId, mTableId);

            return await insertRequest.ExecuteAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other cloud service, BigQuery doesn't offer a 100% uptime SLA (it's actually 99.9%), so it's not uncommon to encounter transient errors like these. We also receive them frequently in our applications.

You need to build exponential backoff-and-retry logic into your application(s) to handle such errors. A good way of doing this is to use a queue to stream your data to BigQuery. This is what we do and it works very well for us.

Some more info:

1. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
2. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request#exp-backoff
3. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery
4. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla

Comment: Exponential backoff is nice to have but not mandatory in this specific service because it is more of a monitoring service. This service is up for about a year and we started to get these errors in the past two months and the amount of them is increasing.

Comment: You could raise a ticket through your Google support channel, but I'm pretty sure they'll give you the same type of response. They told us this when we did it.

Comment: Thanks Graham! I'll give it a try.